# Apply padding to the truncated line of a multiline text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am looking to add padding to the last line of a padding element only. I have the following html using Tailwind classes:

```
<div className="my-3 max-h-[4.5rem] relative">
  <p ref={ref} className="inline-block line-clamp-3 pr-14">{data.description}</p>
  <button className="text-blue-600 leading-none absolute bottom-[-4px] right-0 font-medium px-2 py-1" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
    more
  </button>
</div>
```

The padding right `pr-14` is applied to the entire `p` tag. How can I get this to apply to only the last line? I have tried `block`, `inline` etc and none of them seem to make a difference. Is this possible in CSS?

For context, I am trying to add padding to the last line when I need to show a "more" button. The only alternative I can think of is to do something like the below image, however unsure how to have the text fade into the background (I can't apply a background to the `more` background as it is transparent).

[image]

Comment: you should split your description in multiple `<p>` tags. With this you can target a specific line

Comment: How would you suggest doing that? The width of the paragraph tag is dynamic.

Comment: Its tricky to do that. You can split the words and then add n number of words to each paragraph. Maybe you can elaborate more on the problem you are trying to solve with padding. What is the need to add padding to the last line?

Comment: The question has been updated, including an image.

Comment: If your design requirements are not too strict you can change the position of the more button. [More button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp)

Comment: They aren't which is good, but I can't seem to find another way to do it. The only reasonable designs I can see is either to put the `more` button on top of the text or to the right of eclipsed text.

Comment: Try if this works  {data.descriptionText} <span class="pr-14"></span>. Or instead of adding span with pr-14 add multiple nbsp; as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiline clamping only works with `display: -webkit-box;` thats why you weren't able to apply other `display` properties.

You could use a mask-image with composites to get where you want to. While not worry about background colors not matching etc:

```
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, black 0%, black 0%), linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, transparent 100%);
    -webkit-mask-position: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%, 120px 32px; /*120px is your padding*/
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
```

https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/ZEKYqvr

Dare I say its a pretty disgusting solution. But does what it says on the box.

Answer (score 3):

A pseudo element can do it.

```css
 p {
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:1.2em;
  margin:0;
  text-align:justify;
}

 p:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:2px;
  width:50px; /* the value of padding */
  background:red; /* to illustrate */
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras arcu libero, efficitur quis condimentum ac, lacinia eu lacus. Cras faucibus vel nibh ut porta.  efficitur quis condimentum ac, lacinia eu lacus. Cras faucibus vel nibh ut porta.  efficitur quis condimentum ac, lacinia eu lacus. Cras faucibus vel nibh ut porta. 
  </p>
```

Comment: I have tested this and it can not get it working with line-camp, do you have an example with this css?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to apply padding right for last line. May be you can try this solution

Before closing p tag you can add inline-block div width 1 Px and  padding.

Comment: I tried this however the element is ignored. I tried inline, block and inline-block also with difference widths.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Temani has proven to be ideal for example to allocate a "spacer" at the end of chat-boxes to enable placing extra data and ensuring the chat-text does not conflict with the extra data:

[image: Chat example]

Example:

- In message (1) there's room for the time.
- In message (2) there would be no space for the time and the word "Barcelona" and the timesmap "2:54" would overlap. With this trick it works perfect.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-chat-message">
    <div class="my-text">{{ message.text }}</div>
    <div class="my-display-time">{{ message.displayTimeStamp }}</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-text:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 30px; /* the value of padding */
    background: red; /* to illustrate */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no CSS selector that would apply.

You can only select the first line using the pseudo-element :first-line. At the moment there is no equivalent for the last line, unfortunately.

Probably, some JavaScript or jQuery plugins will can handle this issue.

Comment: Are there any suggestions for javascript that can target the last line rendered in the DOM?

Comment: There's one of simple plugins for that: https://www.cssscript.com/style-last-line-paragraph/

Answer (score -1):

Try use this example, you need to plugin define to use [Line-clamp](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#line-clamp)

###### Add Line-Clamp plugin to use it

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
  ]
}
```

###### tailwind example

```
<!-- max-h-20 = max-height:5rem; -->
<div class="my-3 max-h-20 relative mx-10 border-2 border-gray-200">
  <!-- you need to Line-Clamp plugin define in tailwind.config.css -->
  <p ref="{ref}" class="flex line-clamp-3 p-1">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  </p>
  <button class="text-blue-600 bg-white leading-none absolute -bottom-0.5 right-0 font-medium px-2 my-2">more</button>
</div>
```

***Tailwind Playground*** https://play.tailwindcss.com/ILpf8grjdF